# "npm install -g bigcommerce-stencil/stencil-cli" not successfully running in windows cmd prompt

Tags: javascript, node.js, bigcommerce

After completing all installation successfully on my windows 7 SP1 PC when i try to run:

```
npm install -g bigcommerce-stencil/stencil-cli
```

I get the error in the below screen:

[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChjBF.jpg)

more details : https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/installing-stencil-cli-1

Any help will be really appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: This may be an issue with the access token you created. Can you ensure that you checked repo permissions and not just the individual boxes per the instructions?

Comment: Sorry but i am not much aware of github, but i can say i have created access token from https://github.com/settings/tokens.  i tried multiple times but no result.. Please give steps if you can.. so that i can retry by following them.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/ -- make sure you select the correct OS.

Comment: Cheers, really great help. one error has been resolved and that is "Permission Denied(public key)". But no luck with successful command running, others are remains same. May you can resolve my issue. please need more help. really appreciated your help.

Comment: Also where do i need to select OS as you have mentioned in you comment.. i m totally unaware about it. please provide more details.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm install -g bigcommerce-stencil/stencil-cli`

This command simply clone the "stencil-cli" repo on the path you are running this command in which npm has already installed "globally".

you can do it by another way as below..
Please use [Git BASH for Windows](http://git-for-windows.github.io/) if you have not installed, please installed it first.

`$ git clone https://github.com/bigcommerce-stencil/stencil-cli.git`

Clone the "stencil-cli" repo to the path where you want to run your store.
please note "npm" has already installed in cloning repo.
after successfully cloning "stencil-cli" you may further for next step of [Registering the jspm Instance](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/installing-stencil-cli-1) .

This is the solution for me.. hope this will be helpful to bigcommerce-stencil developers who faces these kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

That did not work for me.  It seems that the path has changed to:

https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil-cli.git

```
git clone https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil-cli.git
Cloning into 'stencil-cli'...
remote: Counting objects: 3319, done.
remote: Total 3319 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 3319
Receiving objects: 100% (3319/3319), 23.31 MiB | 792.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1874/1874), done.
```

Then I ran

```
npm install -g @bigcommerce/stencil-cli
jspm install
npm install
```

Finally got it.